# Include glib library in Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, compiler-errors, glib

I'm not an expert of Makefile.
In my program I'm using hashtables of *glib.h* so in my Makefile I wrote this:

```
exec: bin/test
    bin/test

clean:
    rm -f build/* bin/*

CFLAGS = -g -Wall -Wpedantic -Wno-padded -O $(shell pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0)

INCLUDES = include/*.h

COMMON_DEPS = $(INCLUDES) Makefile

build/%.o: src/%.c $(COMMON_DEPS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

bin/test: /* functions.o*/ $(COMMON_DEPS)
$(CC) -o bin/test /* functions.o*/
```

But when I execute the Makefile I receive a list of these error messages:

```
...
functions.c: undefined reference to "g_str_hash"
functions.c: undefined reference to "g_str_equal"
...
```

I don't understand why

Comment: Your Makefile doesn't really make sense. How would you compile your code manually? What are the commands?

Comment: Are you, by any chance, trying to use `/*` and `*/` as comment delimiters in your makefile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I solved it in this way:

```
exec: bin/test
    bin/test

clean:
    rm -f build/* bin/*

CFLAGS = -g -Wall -Wpedantic -Wno-padded -O $(shell pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0)

LFLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --libs glib-2.0)

INCLUDES = include/*.h

COMMON_DEPS = $(INCLUDES) Makefile

build/%.o: src/%.c $(COMMON_DEPS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

bin/test: /*functions.o */ $(COMMON_DEPS)
    $(CC) -o bin/test /*functions.o */ $(LFLAGS)
```

Answer (score 0):

The crux of the problem is that you're including the link flags in the compile command rather than the link command itself.

Remove `--libs glib-2.0` from `CFLAGS` and add it to a new variable `LFLAGS` that can be used on the link line...

```
exec: bin/test
    bin/test

clean:
    rm -f build/* bin/*

CFLAGS = -g -Wall -Wpedantic -Wno-padded -O $(shell pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0)
LFLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --libs glib-2.0)

INCLUDES = include/*.h

COMMON_DEPS = $(INCLUDES) Makefile

build/%.o: src/%.c $(COMMON_DEPS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

bin/test: /* functions.o*/ $(COMMON_DEPS)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) -o bin/test /* functions.o*/
```

[Note: I've left the rest of the makefile untouched but the dependency specification for `bin/test` does look very odd.]

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a very helpful diagnostic.  What was the link command that was executed and what were the errors?